# Return only records with 6 instances where all values in one column are the same for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a query and got stuck at a point where I am unsure something I am trying to achieve is even possible.

I have build a query which returns results like below:

[image]

with the below query:

```sql
declare @stDate     varchar(10) = '1988-01-01';
declare @fromDate   varchar(10) = '2014-06-01';
declare @toDate     varchar(10) = '2014-11-30';

select  PART.PARTNAME                                                       as 'PART NUMBER'
    ,   PART.PARTDES                                                        as 'DESCRIPTION'
    ,   ( CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, WARHSCOST.CURDATE/1440, @stDate)))     as 'DATE'
    ,   ( CONVERT(float, WARHSCOST.BALANCE ) / 1000 )                       as 'BALANCE' 
    ,   ( CONVERT(decimal(19,2), WARHSCOST.COST) )                          as 'VALUE'

from    WARHSCOST  
    inner join PART         on ( PART.PART = WARHSCOST.PART ) 
    inner join WAREHOUSES   on ( WAREHOUSES.WARHS = WARHSCOST.WARHS ) 

where   ( CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, WARHSCOST.CURDATE/1440, @stDate)) between @fromDate and @toDate ) 
    and ( WAREHOUSES.WARHSNAME = 'Fin' )
    and ( PART.PARTNAME NOT LIKE 'ZZ%' )
    and ( WARHSCOST.COST > 0 )

group by PART.PARTNAME
    ,    PART.PARTDES
    ,    WARHSCOST.CURDATE
    ,    WARHSCOST.BALANCE
    ,    WARHSCOST.COST
    having count(*) > 0 

order by 1 , 4
```

but I wish to restrict the results to only those

[image]

I need to add one more filter/criteria but I am totally lost in how to even go about it:

- show only PARTS which have **the same** balance for all 6 months (*as shown in the second screenshot*)

Any help is much appreciated as it would save me a lot of time iterating through the current recordset just to eliminate the records that don't have the same balance for all 6 months.

If any more information is required from me please just let me know and i will do my best to update the question.

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @PhilipKelley Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)

Comment: There is no such thing as SQL Server 2010. What is the result of select @@VERSION?

Comment: Missed that you put the version number. That is SQL 2008r2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One methodology: load the data you are pulling into a temp table, then analyze and pull what meets your criteria from the temp table. In SQL 2005 and up, you can do all this with CTEs (common table expressions). Without the underlying tables I cannot check the syntax, but the concept here is solid.

Your original query is all but untouched in the first cte below. I've added some `--comments`, just because.

```sql
declare @stDate     varchar(10) = '1988-01-01';
declare @fromDate   varchar(10) = '2014-06-01';
declare @toDate     varchar(10) = '2014-11-30';


WITH cteBase (PartName, PartDes, PartDate, PartBal, PartCost)
 as (

--  CTE pulls out the "basic" data
select  PART.PARTNAME                                                     --  as 'PART NUMBER'
    ,   PART.PARTDES                                                      --  as 'DESCRIPTION'
    ,   ( CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, WARHSCOST.CURDATE/1440, @stDate)))   --  as 'DATE'
    ,   ( CONVERT(float, WARHSCOST.BALANCE ) / 1000 )                     --  as 'BALANCE' 
    ,   ( CONVERT(decimal(19,2), WARHSCOST.COST) )                        --  as 'VALUE'

from    WARHSCOST  
    inner join PART         on ( PART.PART = WARHSCOST.PART ) 
    inner join WAREHOUSES   on ( WAREHOUSES.WARHS = WARHSCOST.WARHS ) 

where   ( CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, WARHSCOST.CURDATE/1440, @stDate)) between @fromDate and @toDate ) 
    and ( WAREHOUSES.WARHSNAME = 'Fin' )
    and ( PART.PARTNAME NOT LIKE 'ZZ%' )
    and ( WARHSCOST.COST > 0 )

group by PART.PARTNAME
    ,    PART.PARTDES
    ,    WARHSCOST.CURDATE
    ,    WARHSCOST.BALANCE
    ,    WARHSCOST.COST
--    having count(*) > 0 --  This doesn't do anything, if count(*) were 0 there would be no row

--order by 1 , 4
    )
 , cteSix (PartName, PartBal)
   as (

--  cte that identifies what from the first cte qualifies
select PartName, PartBal
 from cteBase
 group by PartName, PartBal
 having count(*) = 6

    )

SELECT
   ba.PartName  as  [PART NUMBER]  --  Embedded space
  ,ba.PartDes   as  DESCRIPTION
  ,ba.PartDate  as  [DATE]         --  Reserved word
  ,ba.PartBal   as  BALANCE
  ,ba.PartCost  as  VALUE
 from cteBase ba
  inner join cteSix six
   on six.PartName = ba.PartName
 order by ba.PartName, ba.PartBal
```

Also, if WARHSCOST.CURDATE is a date datatype (as opposed to string or integer), you shouldn't need to CONVERT it to date.

Comment: I just had a [quick read on CTEs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265371/Common-Table-Expressions-CTE-in-SQL-SERVER) and modified your code and been able to achieve exactly what I needed. Let me submit a little update on your current answer and Thank you very much for help!

Comment: `WARHSCOST.CURDATE` is actually an `Int` data type cuz `2014-06-30` is stored as `13934880` in the db. Its just the way this ERP system stores dates... sad ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about adding

```
having count(distinct CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, WARHSCOST.CURDATE/1440, @stDate))) = 6
and count(distinct WARHSCOST.BALANCE) = 1
```

Comment: I tried having count = 6 but there is more group by columns which would only show records where there 6 equal dates and balances. Thats not what I am after.

Comment: Might be tricky to work out the details, but this should be much easier to implement than my monster.

Comment: @CrimsonKing something is not right. The current code gives me 0 results :/

Comment: I still feel a solution can be done with this tactic. However, it probably involves using `count()... over ()...` logic, which I find very hard to puzzle out.